# how to iterate element child's from bottom to top

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, reverse

I have a table.

I will now iterate the `<tr>` elements which are child's from the element `<tbody>` from bottom to top.

This code will iterate the child's from top to bottom.

```
$.each($('#tbody').children(), function( key, value ) {
    // do magic
});
```

`$('#tbody').children().reverse()` will not work...

Comment: Try `$.each($("#tbody").children.get().reverse(),function() { /* ... */ });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
$('#tbody').children().get().reverse()
```

ie

```
$.each($('#tbody').children().get().reverse(), function( key, value ) {
    // do magic
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GEERv/)

Comment: You beat me by 10 seconds :P

Answer (score 3):

```
var children = $('#tbody').children();
for (var i = children.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  //Do something with children[i]
}
```